# Como faço para encontrar os nomes na lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Complete a função `buscar(lista, animal)` abaixo, que recebe dois valores:
>
> - Uma lista com nomes de animais.
> - O nome de um animal que deseja-se encontrar na lista.
>
> A função deve retornar `True` caso o animal exista na lista, e `False` caso o contrário.
>
> Ao finalizar a função, execute o programa e teste-o com alguns animais da lista.
>
> Sugestões:
>
> - tatu (existe na lista)
> - coelho (não existe na lista)
>
> Abaixo está o código:
>
> ```
> def buscar(lista, animal):
>   pass  # comando inútil (você pode apagá-lo se quiser)
>   # Complete o código faltante aqui!
>
> # Programa principal: NÃO MODIFIQUE O CÓDIGO ABAIXO
> def programa_principal():
>   lista_animais = ['avestruz', 'cachorro', 'cavalo', 'gato', 'papagaio', 'tatu', 'urso', 'zebra']
>   
>   bicho = input('Informe um animal: ')
>   while bicho != '':
>       if buscar(lista_animais, bicho):
>           print(bicho, 'existe na lista!')
>       else:
>           print(bicho, 'não existe na lista!')
>       bicho = input('\nInforme um animal: ')
>
> programa_principal()
> ```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Parece que a sua pergunta contém alguns problemas. Nós não faremos o seu trabalho da faculdade ou lição de casa, mas se você estiver com dificuldade em alguma parte específica, compartilhe o seu código, diga o que já tentou fazer e qual está sendo a dificuldade, assim você aumenta as suas chances em conseguir uma boa resposta. Não deixe de ler o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/100416) para ter uma experiência melhor por aqui.

Answer (score 2):

Para verificar se um elemento existe na lista — ou mesmo em qualquer objeto que possua o método `__contains__`  — utilize a "keyword" `in` da seguinte forma:

```
def buscar(lista, animal):
    # Verifica se "animal" é um elemento que está dentro da lista.
    return animal in lista
```

O que essa "keyword" faz é chamar implicitamente o método `__contains__` — que retorna um valor booleano — passando como argumento o elemento à esquerda do `in`.

Sabendo disso, podemos criar uma classe com nossas próprias regras para validar se o objeto possui ou não um determinado elemento. Veja a situação abaixo:

```
class Jogo:
    
    def __init__(self, jogador1, jogador2):
        self.__jogador1 = jogador1
        self.__jogador2 = jogador2

    def __contains__(self, jogador):
        if jogador == self.__jogador1 or jogador == self.__jogador2: return True
        else: return False

jogo = Jogo("David", "Bruno")

print("Gabriel" in jogo) # False
print("David" in jogo)   # True
```

No exemplo acima, é verificado se os jogadores Gabriel e David estão no jogo. Em ambas as verificações, o método `__contains__` é invocado, tendo o nome do jogador — string à esquerda do `in` — sendo passado para o parâmetro `jogador` do método, onde o elemento será validado, retornando `True` ou `False`.